# Set Layout for Single paged application in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC and trying to create a single paged application.

My Content in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
    @Html.Action("Index", "MenuNavigation", "U01")

    @RenderBody()
</section>
```

Note:  `@Html.Action("Index", "MenuNavigation", "U01")` is the place where I'm rendering my dynamic Navigation menu from database(will load only once from DB)

Below is my `_MainLayout.cshtml` that uses `_Layout.cshtml` as master page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml"; 
}

<div id="MainPageContent">
@RenderBody()
</div>
```

Here is my `Home\Index` view will looks like

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    if (ViewBag.IsRequestFromLoginPage !=null && ViewBag.IsRequestFromLoginPage)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = null;
    }
}
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h2>Home</h2>
```

here is the respective `Home` controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.IsRequestFromLoginPage = TempData[Constants.TempData.IsUserFromLogin];
    TempData[Constants.TempData.IsUserFromLogin] = false;
    return View();
}
```

When user logged-in to my site I wanted to render my `Home\Index` and load my Nav Menu(partial content) only on the first load.

If User select any of the menu item, I'm doing AJAX call to update the `MainPageContent` in `_MainLayout.cshtml` by this way I'm trying to create the single paged application but problem is when User refresh the page from browser URL. For example: If User is in "MyApp.com/Home" and refresh the browser it causes my application looses its _layout (render only home content) because of the `ViewBag.IsRequestFromLoginPage` check in my `Home` page.

Not sure is this the correct way to achieve this. Is there any alternative to do so. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is how my Layout is looks like>
[image: My MVC Layout]

@Daniel
[image: For Daniel reference]

Comment: Change your if condition to test only if it's null or not. Like `if(ViewBag.IsRequestFromLoginPage != null)`

Comment: @jamiedanq But I'm not sure is this the correct way of doing it. If I make a request to Home again inside home it will duplicate the _layout content inside my maincontent.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit redundant, why do you have `@RenderBody()` in `_MainLayout.cshtml` if you say its master layout is `_Layout.cshtml` which also calls `@RenderBody`? instead of using `@Html.Action` and `@RenderBody()` use `Html.RenderAction` (When calling a differente method that's not index) and don't specify a Layout for your that view, in that same way, get rid of all the validations to see if it comes from the login page or not, note that Index method always enters by default so there's actually not even a need of calling any type of HTML action if you're accessing your Home Controller, you could leave your main layout like this

```
<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">   
<div id="MainPageContent">
@RenderBody()
</div>

</section>
```

and your Index view like this:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h2>Home</h2>
```

In a different ActionResult method you can load the same view as Index like this:

```
public ActionResult update(){
return View("Index");
}
```

You'd then make the AJAX call to fill the "MainContentPage" div with that method instead of "Index".

Comment: I tried doing the same way which you mentioned, but problem is I'm doing AJAX call to update my content that was actually repeating my content when I click Home link inside in my menu. Please refer the image which I attached now.@Daniel

Comment: Don't  make the ajax call to "Home" itself but to "Home/Index" or don't do an AJAX call at all when clicking home, just refresh the page. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Do you want me to prevent AJAX call to Home ? @Daniel

Comment: Guess, that will work. Let me try and get back to you. Thanks. @Daniel